# How to boot from external HDD?

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I have HDD from my old laptop with installed Ubuntu 14.04. It works perfectly when I put it on my other laptop (HP 6730b), but when I put it in an external case and try boot from it I get this:

```
error: no such partition.

Entering rescue mode...

grub rescue>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Some very old IDE based BIOS and somewhat newer old USB drives do not see bootable partitions beyond 137GB. Is your / (root) large or beyond 137GB? Often then better to have either a smaller /  of about 25GB and separate /home to use rest of drive or have a /boot partition at beginning of drive.

Comment: the size of the partition is 28.3 GB

Comment: May be best to see details:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info